# Embedding Website Data and Current local IP address in raspimonitor/another website?

Tags: linux, webserver, debian, raspberry-pi

I hope I'm able to specify my question as good as possible,since I'm German and my computer specific vocabulary lacks a few expressions from time to time..

Anyway: I got a raspberry pi with `raspimonitor` running that shows a website with some system-data if you connect to, on port 8888. 
How can i make the software also show my internal and external IP adress and some data from a website(on which you have to be logged in).

Im not a complete newbie, but relatively new to debian and coding, so IDK if this is even possible for me to do, but I'd be very happy if someone could give me a hint or something similliar how to reach my aim.

Comment: Whats `raspimonitor`? Can you provide some link or similar? I was not able to find it via Google, but we have to know it to be able to help. I guess one has to edit the source code of some web scripts.

Comment: service-scan says: "sun answerbook http server. Or gnump3d streaming music server"